# How to solve the error Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.0.0 with Eclipse in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, maven

I imported a maven project to Eclipse and got the following error in pom.xml:

```
Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.0.0 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/../lib/tools.jar
```

My operating system is Ubuntu 18.04 and the Java version is

```
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Is the problem because the `tools.jar` is not located in the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib`? If that is the case, where can I find this `tools.jar`?

Comment: The tools.jar does not exist anymore you need to change the package or you have to use max. JDK8 ...

Answer (score 0):

The tools.jar library was removed in Java 9 as part of [JEP 220](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220). The compiler tools from this jar were moved into the JDK's lib folder.

The best way to deal with this is to upgrade the dependency that requires tools.jar with a version that is Java 9+ compatible.

Barring that, you might be able to find the classes you need in the javac.compiler module, but that path is fraught with peril (or at the very least heartburn).

Comment: `The best way to deal with this is to upgrade the dependency that requires tools.jar with a version that is Java 9+ compatible`  What do you mean by this

Comment: Maven doesn't require tools.jar.  That means some plugin or dependency is depending on it, and needs to be replaced with a version that is Java 9 compatible.